# MVC 4 Mobile Views Not Being Rendered Correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having the exact same issue as listed on following page. Also tried everything that is being said in the forums but could not get it working. Any help please?????

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Display Modes Stop Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354188/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-display-modes-stop-working/12118815)

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is a bug in MVC 4 RC.
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/280